# query result into non repeating json format

Tags: json, codeigniter

I am fetching data by using left join in Codeigniter

[image]
And checking the response in postman

[image]
excerciseID, videoURL and intructions are table columns.
In response excerciseID, videoURL are same and intructions is different.

Instead I want response to be like this or similar:

```
{
 "status":true
 "message":"success",
 "exercise":[
         "excerciseID":"",
         "videoURL":"",
         "intructions":[value1,value2,value3]
 ]
}
```

Please any kind of help/guide.
Thanks in advance

Comment: please edit your question to include the actual codes instead of image of codes

Comment: also, you should mention how you `json_encode` that query results